# Left join using a different or not equal in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, left-join

I have to build a query to get users that did not received and alert about new posts.

My relevant table structure is as follows:

Posts: postId int
Users: userId int, email varchar
PostAlertUsers: postAlertUserId int, postId int, userId int

All related fields have FK constraints between tables.

I've built this query in SQL but couldn't find a way to work in Entity Framework:

```
SELECT u.email
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Posts p ON p.userId != u.userId 
LEFT JOIN PostAlertUsers pu ON u.userId = pu.userId AND p.postId = pu.postId 
WHERE pu.postAlertUserId IS NULL
```

I've wrote the following EF query, but didn't got the same results:

```
from u in context.Users
join pu in context.PostAlertUsers on u.userId equals pu.userId into postAlerts
from pa in postAlerts.DefaultIfEmpty()
join p in context.Posts on pa.postId equals p.postId
where pa.userId != u.userId
select u.email;
```

How can I get the same results using linq to entities. Using the dot syntax (I don't know the correct term for `DbSet.Where(x => ...)` syntax) would be even better.

**Edit:**

I want to get all users that didn't have a record on `PostAlertUsers` for each `Post` in `Posts` that isn't from the same user.

**Edit 2:**

Trying to clarify a bit more:

I want to warn users about new posts from other users only one time for each post and my routine will run every hour to check if there are anyone to send a message.

I want to get all users that aren't already warned about a post so it will not have a record on `PostAlertUsers` for this user and post combination but will have a record on Posts from a user other that itself.

Example data:

```
Users
------------------------
userid | email
------------------------
1      | email1@test.com
2      | email2@test.com
3      | email3@test.com
------------------------

Posts (posts are created by users)
------------------------
postId | userId
------------------------
1      | 1
2      | 3
3      | 1
------------------------

PostAlertUsers (every time a user is notified about a new post, one record is added here)
------------------------
postId | userId
------------------------
1      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 1
------------------------
```

The resulting query would output this data:

```
Result (using postId and userId to identify what user have to be notified for what post)
---------------------------------
postId | userId | email
---------------------------------
2      | 2      | email2@test.com
3      | 2      | email2@test.com
3      | 3      | email3@test.com
---------------------------------
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to AD.Net I've came up with the following:

```
from u in context.Users
let posts = contexto.Posts.Where(p => p.userId != u.userId)
from p in posts
join pau in context.PostAlertUsers on u.userId equals pau.userId 
into alerts
from a in alerts.DefaultIfEmpty()
where a == null || a.postId != p.postId
orderby p.idPost
select new {
    p.postId,
    u.userId,
    u.email
}
```

Answer (score 1):

edited:
Another attempt from different angle, not sure about performance, might be just as bad as `cross-join`

```
       from p in context.Posts
       let otherUsers = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserId != p.User.UserId)
       from u in otherUsers
       join pau in alerts on u.UserId equals pau.User.UserId into alert
       from a in alert.DefaultIfEmpty()
       where a == null || a.Post.PostId != p.PostId
       select new {p.PostId, u.Email};
```

Here's a LinqPad attempt:

```
void Main()
{
     var users = new List<User>{new User{UserId = 1}, new User{UserId = 2}};
            var posts = new List<Post>
            {
                new Post{PostId = 1, User = new User{UserId = 2}},
                new Post{PostId = 2, User = new User{UserId = 1}},
                new Post{PostId = 3, User = new User{UserId = 2}},
            };
            var alerts = new List<PostUserAlert>
            {
                new PostUserAlert{Post = new Post{PostId = 1}, 
                                    User = new User{UserId = 1}}
            };

            var result = (from p in posts
                let otherUsers = users.Where(u => u.UserId != p.User.UserId)
                from u in otherUsers
                join pau in alerts on u.UserId equals pau.User.UserId into alert
                from a in alert.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where a == null || a.Post.PostId != p.PostId
                select new {p.PostId, u.UserId}).ToList();

                result.Dump();
}


 class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }

        public List<PostUserAlert>  PostUserAlerts { get; set; }
    }

    class PostUserAlert
    {
        public Post Post { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
// Define other methods and classes here
```

Comment: It's a 1 to 1 relationship. Your first option works well. It only misses that I want to get the users that haven't been alerted, so I've changed the `where` clause to `where pa.Post.userId != u.userId && pa = null` and it worked as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Ops... my bad! I've tested it now and with my addition it returns nothing. I may be missing something, but it will not return what I've expected. I need users that did not received the alert, so I've to get `users` that didn't have a record on `PostAlertUsers` for each `Post` in `Posts` that isn't from the same user.

Comment: Not sure if I followed your logic correctly, but please check the update.

Comment: Almost there. I want to warn users about new posts from other users only one time for each post and my routine will run every hour. I've to get all users that aren't already warned about a post so, it will not have a record on `PostAlertUsers` for this user and post but will have a record on `Posts` from a user other that itself. Hope I've made me clearer and thank you for the effort.

Comment: Yeah. Your query did the job. The results are the expected and the generated SQL query is close to my original query. I'm making some more tests to make sure it's the correct solution.

Comment: I've used your query with slightly modifications. Thank you!

Comment: Oops again... The query worked great for a single record on the posts table, but as soon I've inserted some records on the bookkeeping table, it began to return duplicated records.